# SymPy polynomial division returns unexpected result

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x a')
(x, a)
>>> div(x**3+a*x*2-5*x+6,x-3)
(2*a + x**2 + 3*x + 4, 6*a + 18)
```

Not much I can tell you except that I expected that this would give me a remainder of 9*a + 18.

What am I missing? What should I have done?

Comment: The result seems correct. Why do you expect `9*a` instead of `6*a`? `simplify((2*a+x**2+3*x+4)*(x-3)+6*a+18-(x**3+a*x*2-5*x+6))==0` gives `True`.

Comment: @Georgy: Perplexing. Remainder must be zero for x-3 to be a factor. 9*a+18=0 gives an 'a' that works, the remainder provided by the div function does not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it's not working. `6*a+18=0` gives `a=-3`. For this `a` the quotient will be `x**2+3*x-2` and if we multiply it by `x-3` we will get `x**3*-11*x+6` which equals the original dividend with `a` substituted by `-3`. If we do the same check for `a=-2`, they will not match.